# Flutter - SQflite : Performance issues while bulk insertion

Tags: flutter, database-performance, bulkinsert, sqflite

Using the below approach for bulk insertions, getting performance issues in flutter app

```
Future<List<Object?>> bulkInsert(String tableName,List<Map<String,dynamic>> rowList) async{
final db = await instance;
int dbSaveResult = 0;
if(db!=null){
  await db.transaction((txn)async {
    var batch = txn.batch();
    for (var rowData in rowList) {
      try {
        batch.insert(tableName, rowData,
            conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
      }
      catch(exception){
        throw "some error while insertion";
      }
    }
    await batch.commit(continueOnError: false);
  });
}
return [];}
```

List<Map<String,dynamic>> : Map contains 4 pairs of keys/value and list length around number of 13032, so total execution time of bulkInsert() method is **3.274 seconds** in flutter.

while the same approach with same data, we are using in native [transaction support using sqlite c library] for insert/update purpose then it takes around **210 milliseconds** only.

any reason, why flutter based solutions taking time? or anything wrong with given code??

Please help me with best approach if I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

Possible optimization:

- Use the `noResult: true` option during commit. It avoid an extra query after each insertion. You will likely get a 50% gain
- You can try to use `sqflite_common_ffi` along with `flitter3_sqlite_libs` ([instructions](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite_common_ffi/doc/using_ffi_instead_of_sqflite.md)). In my experiment it is about twice faster
- You can run the solution above without running the sqlite statements in a separate isolate (but that could hang the UI)

A quick benchmark I tried (13000 records, 4 fields, Pixel 4a) gives this result:

```
sqflite io
insert: 0:00:04.074015
insert (noResult): 0:00:02.133279

sqflite_ffi io
insert: 0:00:01.915051
insert (noResult): 0:00:01.319466

sqflite_ffi (no isolate) io
insert: 0:00:01.420478
insert (noResult): 0:00:01.058417
```

Flutter services (for sqflite) and cross isolation communication (for sqlite ffi) are likely the main bottleneck. You could try to use sqflite3 package (i.e. without sqflite package) directly for even better performance.